# How to resolve TypeError: string indices must be integers, while applying lambda function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am applying a `lambda` function on my `DataFrame`. But I think I am doing it wrong.
What is the correct way to apply `lambda` function ?

**input**:

ID  Name    result  old_result

A1  Jim Bad Good

A2  Tim Good    Good

A3  Matt    Good    None

**code**:

```
df3['avg_result'] = df3['result'].apply(lambda x : x['old_result'] if x['result'] == 'Bad' else x['result'])
```

**Expected Output**:

ID  Name    result  old_result  avg_result

A1  Jim Bad Good    Good

A2  Tim Good    Good    Good

A3  Matt    Good    None    Good

Answer (score 2):

You are doing `df['result'].apply(lambda x ...)` so the value of `x` actually is each individual string in the column df['result']. That's why when you try to do x['old_result'], it says "string indices must be integers" because it is doing something like `Good['old_result']` which is not possible.

What you need is

```
df['avg_result'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['old_result'] if x['result'] == 'Bad' else x['result'], axis=1)
```

What this does is instead of applying the lambda function to each string in df['result'] column, it applies the function to each row in the dataframe (that's where `axis=1` comes in).

And within that row you can then do `x['old_result']` and it will return you the value of `old_result` column in that row.

#### Output

```
   ID   Name    result  old_result  avg_result
0   A1  Jim     Bad     Good    Good
1   A2  Tim     Good    Good    Good
2   A3  Matt    Good    None    Good
```

#### Recommendation

In fact, you can do the same thing in a much more readable manner with [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) instead of using `.apply` and lambda

```
df['npwhere_result'] = np.where(df['result']=='Bad', df['old_result'], df['result'])

    ID  Name    result  old_result  avg_result  npwhere_result
0   A1  Jim     Bad     Good         Good       Good
1   A2  Tim     Good    Good         Good       Good
2   A3  Matt    Good    None         Good       Good
```